# JSON to Database with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

So I have this JSON for example

```
    {  
  "top" : [
    {
      "info" : {
        "ID" : 0,
        "TID" : 1
      },
      "geo" : {
        "poins" : [
          [
            [
              -5.9,
              57.1
            ],
            [
              -5.99,
              57.0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "info" : {
        "ID" : 1,
        "TID" : 2
      },
      "geo" : {
        "points" : [
          [
            [
              -5.4,
              57.0
            ],
            [
              -5.9,
              57.0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

I need to put this information in the DataBase with php
So I have a colum in the DB called points and it need the data inside to be looking like:

```
[-5.4, 57.0],[-5.9, 57.0]
```

I have a columb with ID so all I need is to put the points from the JSON for every ID

My php should be loking like:
connection to the database

```
    $str = file_get_contents(the JSON);
            $json = json_decode($str, true); 
            foreach ($json['top'] as $field) {
                query='UPDATE poins_table
                SET points='$field['geo']['points']'
                 WHERE ID='$field['info']['ID']' '
        }
```

The code seems to be not working. What I am missing ...Any siggestions will be helpfull. Thank you

Comment: Where is your DB connection? What kind of DB? Did you try anything?

Comment: I am using MySQL and it is not the  connection problem.. All I need is to get the information from every single point with the id from the JSON so it should be with foreach ..the rest is not so important ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try following:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('the JSON URL');
$json = json_decode($str, true); 

try{
  $db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
  $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE poins_table SET points=? WHERE ID=?');

  foreach ($json['top'] as $field) {
    $query->execute(array(json_encode($field['geo']['points']), $field['info']['ID']));
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo "Error: ". $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: If this is not the solution how it shoudl be looking... If you only know that you have this JSON and you need to place it in the database...how your code will be looking like

Comment: @ГеоргиДаскалов Sorry, if you can not start with this, I can not help you further.